# Qt QGraphicsProxyWidget never receives dragEnterEvent

Tags: c++, qt, events

I am trying to do drag and drop between widgets added to QGraphicScene with addWidget.

I implementing drag and drop as Qt documentation suggests:

- Enabling drops with setAcceptDrops(true) for target widget
- In my mousePressEvent I am creating QDrag object run QDrag::exec() for this object.

but dragEnterEvent is never called nor for my custom widget neither for proxywidget returned by addWidget.

Other events are forwarded to my widget ok.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you have to reimplement the dragEnterEvent in your child-widget, means it's not enough to just call `setAcceptDrops(true)` for the widget. What happens then is that the child widget calls it's `dragEventEnter`-function, but by default it does nothing. How should the childwidget know about your `dragEventEnter`-function in the main-window? It has to be in the child-widget itself, so you have to subclass it, like in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/dnd.html) explained.

Comment: That is exactly what I do and it works outside QGraphicScene.